# Navigation Mode in Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android

I use Sherlock Action Bar in my application.And I have a problem in navigationMode.

**Snapshot :**

[image]

My code

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle("проверяем");
    // выпадающий список
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    listList = listList();
    if (listList != null) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, listList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);//android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // adapter

        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter,
                (OnNavigationListener) this);
    }

    setTitle("sdcdcsc");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

May be problem that I use ABS 4.4 on device android 2.3? What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] actions = new String[] { "Hotel", "Motel", "Pensiuni & Vile", "Camping"};
            myArrayAdaptor<String> adptr = new myArrayAdaptor<String>(getBaseContext(),R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);
    /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


    /** Defining Navigation listener */
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition,long itemId) 
        {
            //other stuffs
            return true;
        }
    };

    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adptr, navigationListener);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

> Try like this